# jQuery Animation + bootstrap - first slideToggle wrong, subsequent cycles correct

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slidetoggle, toggleclass

I'm implementing a slide-down, slide-up navigation element for mobile view on a website (so that navigation is available on demand and doesn't hinder reading).

Scripts included in this page are:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="site.js"></script>
```

There is a bootstrap nav button fixed at the top left of the viewport, called NavXSButton, which calls the following javascript function onclick():

```
function XSNavToggle() {
    if ($('#NavXS').is(':visible') == true)
    {
        $('#NavXS').slideToggle('slow', function () {
            $('#NavXS').toggleClass('hidden-xs visible-xs');
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $('#NavXS').toggleClass('hidden-xs');
        $('#NavXS').slideToggle('slow', function () {
            $('#NavXS').toggleClass('visible-xs');
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

The intent is that the button shall toggle visibility of the DIV with ID NavXS, animating it sliding in from the top or sliding out to the top. The NavXS DIV is hidden by default because hidden-xs is explicitly specified in the DIV's class list and visible-xs is not specified:

```
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg row OrangeGradient" id="NavXS" style="position:fixed; top: 0px; left: 0; z-index: 999998;">
```

When I click the button the FIRST time, I see:

- The NavXS DIV shows itself immediately
- The NavXS DIV then slides AWAY
- The NavXS DIV shows itself again immediately at the end of the animation

I expect it should just slide IN from the top.

Every subsequent click (show/hide) works exactly as expected. If the DIV is currently visible, it slides neatly away; if it's hidden, it slides into place.

Now that I've set the stage, can someone explain:

1. Why the **first** animation is broken
2. How to fix it (style order? Initialisation of something?)